# how to create a dynamic url for an embedded java sqlite database

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

i coded a java sqlite db connector class that works. but the problem i have is that any time i am to use the connector with the same db on another computer i will have to change the location of the db in my connectDb(...) method. pls is there a way i can over come that? here is my db connector class:

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaConnect {

public static Connection ConnectDb() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\IDEProjects\\myApp\\MYAppDB.sqlite");

        return conn;
    } catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: put this path into settings file or pass as command line argument

Comment: @Lashane the problem is that the path will change depending on the computer the app is going to be run...

Comment: so you will have either different configuration files or launch commands for each computer, also - you can put your file in the same folder where executable

Comment: @Lashane well...i dont think that will be a feasible solution because if the app using this db connector is going to be a distributed app, there is no way you are going to keep track of every client computer that the app is going to run on!

Comment: you don't need to track every client, during installation you will ask for path, write it to settings file and application will use this settings file during run

Comment: @Lashane ok please do you have an idea how i can code that?

Comment: sure I have ideas how to code this, at least 10 or 15 different ideas, my hourly rate as teacher is $100, when we can start?

Comment: @Lashane hahahaha you are kidding right? :D